# Springboot-- How to use @Profile with value having regular expression?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a class in my springboot maven project. I want to annotate Class with @Profile in a way that this class should not be configured for any profile ending with '-test'.

ConfigureData class is under /main.

Under my /test directory, I have couple of tests classes annotated with @ActiveProfiles as 'unit-test', 'integration-test', 'functional-test', 'system-test' etc.

I am trying something like below to ignore auto configuration of 'ConfigureData' class for all the profiles ending with '-test', but it is not working!

Is there a way to achieve this using some regular expression without specifying name of each and every test profile under @Profile?

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!.*-test")
public class ConfigureData {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't say for SPeL I know that it supports Regex with "matches" (special word), however, I think its too fragile, so I propose another way: Use Conditional with custom condition.

In fact `@Profile` introduced in Spring 3.x was rewritten in spring 4 to be implemented with a more flexible "Conditional approach".

Take a look at the source code of profile annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Conditional(ProfileCondition.class)
public @interface Profile {

    /**
     * The set of profiles for which the annotated component should be registered.
     */
    String[] value();

}
```

Note that Profile is implemented as "Conditional" and it has a custom condition that examines all the currently running profiles and decides whether condition matches or not.

Here is an implementation of Condition in Spring 4:

```
class ProfileCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        if (context.getEnvironment() != null) {
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> attrs = metadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(Profile.class.getName());
            if (attrs != null) {
                for (Object value : attrs.get("value")) {
                    if (context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles(((String[]) value))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

So you can create your own annotation like `@Production` annotate with your custom Condition that checks the profiles and if the're test - do not match or something.

Then put `@Production` on the configuration (class `ConfigureData` in the question) and you're done!

Comment: Thanks! Though I was looking primarily for regular expression approach, but alternatively your solution looks good too!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think wild card is supported in profile expression. Multiple profiles can be mentioned within @Profile sticking to have only supported operators.

Spring official documentation says,

The following operators are supported in profile expressions:

```
! - A logical not of the profile
& - A logical and of the profiles
| - A logical or of the profiles
```

The complete detail can be found here,
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Profiles.html#of-java.lang.String...-